# Unable to make an object immutable

Tags: scala

I want to make a call to a server but if and only if the data (remoteIdKey in this case) is outdated. Here is how I'm doing it:

```
object remoteCaller {

 def getRemoteKeyId = {

   // do we need to get the data from the server?
   if (currentTime - lastCallTime >= 1000) {
      remoteId = makeRemoteCall
      lastCallTime = currentTime
    }

    remoteId
  }

  private var remoteId = 0
  private def currentTime = //....
  private var lastCallTime = //....
  private def makeRemoteCall = { //remote call to the server to get the remote Id key} 
}
```

The problem is that I mutate the state of `remoteCaller` and, therefore use `var` instead of `val`. And I also want use object instead of class to insure there it will be only instance of it.

How can I make remoteCaller immutable or how do I do it the functional style (without mutation)?

Comment: I think you should consider whether or not the problem you are trying to solve is inherently stateful. To me it seems like things that can be outdated must be mutable. Any I/O is inherently mutable and therefore might not benefit from a purely functional approach. While it is considered best practice to use val's as often as possible, it is by no means mandatory.

Comment: If you decide to keep things the way they are, you'll have some synchronization concerns to deal with.  Might want to consider breaking this up into two pieces.  One that fetches the remote data on a fixed interval and the other is the operation to get that data.  Locking while you make a remote call is probably not ideal.  This way, you only lock while you change out the variable when the periodic task updates it.

Comment: @cmbaxter, how do I do that? I though about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you want to achieve two things which are mutually exclusive:

1. Mutable state
2. An `object` with only vals in it

As @Felix has already stated, having mutable state is not inherently bad. In such a case as yours, I'd consider it okay, especially if it helps to avoid unnecessary complexity. But nonetheless, you could clean it up a little bit. First of all, I would wrap the mutable state that you currently have into a new class. For example:

```
case class RemoteCall(remoteId: Int, lastCallTime: Int) {
    def refresh():RemoteCall = {
        if (currentTime - lastCallTime >= 1000) {
            RemoteCall(makeRemoteCall, currentTime)
        } else {
            this
        }
    }

    private def makeRemoteCall = { ... }
}
```

In your `RemoteCaller` object, you'd then do something like this:

```
object RemoteCaller {

    // Your entire mutable state wrapped in a case class
    private var remoteCall:RemoteCall = ...

    def getRemoteKeyId = {
        remoteCall = remoteCall.refresh
        remoteCall.remoteId
    }

}
```

Comment: but still RemoteCaller has a mutable field var remoteCall.

Comment: Yep, as I said, it is simply not possible to have an object with mutable state that only consists of vals, as that would be contradictory. While it is good to avoid mutable state if possible, there are times where you might want to use a `var` nonetheless, for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: I'm curious, why did you make RemoteCall to be a case class?

Comment: Well, for one you get the nicer creation syntax through the auto-generated apply method: `RemoteCaller(foo,bar)` instead of `new RemoteCaller(foo, bar)`. Another nice feature is the auto-generated `toString` method. Mainly though, I often use pattern matching, and case classes make that pretty easy :)

Comment: Also, it might be better to make class RemoteCall be nested in RemoteCaller. What do you think?

Comment: That is definitely an option, depending on whether or not you are using it anywhere else. If you are sure you'll never need it elsewhere, go ahead and nest it. It is very difficult to say without knowing the "big picture" ;) Also, you might want to read [A Tour of Scala: Inner Classes](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/115) to learn about the difference between Java's and Scala's inner classes :)

Comment: Your example is good, but I'm curious about how to do the same in pure functional approach without any mutation at all. Is it possible and would you mind showing me how to do that?